Creating a sequence table with different column counts
I'm hoping to create a TOCOL in excel of an array of values based on variable criteria.
Eg. When it meets one criteria, I wish for it to be able to return an array of values associated with that criteria (eg stores in that region), and when it meets another criteria return values associated to that criteria.



Sales
Region
Number of stores
Criteria




www
WA
3
FALSE


xxx
WA
3
TRUE


yyy
NSW
2
TRUE


zzz
VIC
4
TRUE



There would be another table to lookup data which I wish to return (eg replenishment stock)
Tried playing around with SEQUENCE and TOCOL and I am reliably able to get a static value
=IFERROR(TOCOL(CHOOSE(SEQUENCE(1,COUNTIF(\_sloc_repl\[Repl type\],XLOOKUP(TEXTAFTER(CELL("filename",$A$1),"\]"),\_tool\[Material type\],\_tool\[Repl type\])),1,0),FILTER(\_tool\[Criteria\],\_tool\[Criteria\]=TEXTAFTER(CELL("filename",$A$1),"\]"))),,0),"")
In this case I can get a result of
xxx
xxx
xxx
yyy
yyy
yyy
zzz
zzz
zzz

(which is a sequence based on the count of the first criteria found [3])
What I am hoping to achieve is
xxx
xxx
xxx
yyy
yyy
zzz
zzz
zzz
zzz

Which is a limited repeat of the value associated to the matching criteria

You may give a try to the following formula-
=TOCOL(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN("",1,REPT(FILTER(A2:A5,D2:D5=TRUE)&"|",FILTER(C2:C5,D2:D5=TRUE))),"|",,1),1)



Another solution:
=TOCOL(IF(D2:D5,IF(SEQUENCE(1,MAX(C2:C5))>C2:C5,0/0,A2:A5),0/0),2)



Apply this formula for the table range
=DROP(TOCOL(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,IF(D2:D5,REPT(A2:A5&"|",C2:C5),"")),"|")),-1)
or as @Harun24hr proposed:
=TOCOL(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,IF(D2:D5,REPT(A2:A5&"|",C2:C5),"")),"|",,TRUE))


You can omit DROP() function by selecting ingore_empty parameter as true of TEXTSPLIT() function. =TOCOL(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,IF(D2:D5,REPT(A2:A5&"|",C2:C5),"")),"|",,1)).
